# Is it possible to convert an existing Windows 7 installation to a WIM and continue using it?

Tags: windows-7, windows-10, boot, multi-boot, wim

I switched to using a new fully licenced Windows 10 (not an upgrade). Unfortunately, MS Windows operating systems were never meant to run side by side, so reconfigurations without re-installations are a bit of a hassle and sometimes not possible.  If I can get Windows 7 to continue to boot and operate from a WIM on the Windows 10 partition, then I might be able to continue using the content in Windows 7 that cannot be transferred to Windows 10.  All the documentation I have read so far is targeted at setting up new specialized versions of Windows 7, so I need to know how to preserve everything except the BOOT Configuration and how configure a new boot item for a WIM.

Comment: If this should prove impossible, I'd be happy to convert this question and take up again the enormous challenge of transferring deeply embedded, now-unsupported licenses and content from Windows 7 to Windows 10...  That would definitely free up storage space currently used to hold all of Windows 7, but it would take weeks of daily hours that I don't have available right now.

Comment: I think the problem is mainly one of licensing. Microsoft expire the Win 7 licence shortly after you upgrade a WIn 7 installation to Win 10. You can dual-boot 7 and 10 but typical [guidance](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-windows_install/how-to-dual-boot-windows-10-and-windows-7-after/7e43130f-11a9-4167-832e-97ed168ae369?auth=1) assumes a clean install of 7 and a separate licence.

Comment: Good point, but in this case I purchased Windows 10 Pro fully and kept my Windows 7 because I knew I would still need it.

Comment: You're probably OK then. I don't know enough to write a good answer though. Do consider editing your question to include material from both your comments. Comments are not regarded as permanent hereabouts and often get tidied up (deleted, moved to chat, etc).